# Casting during an if-else statement

Tags: java, variables, if-statement, variable-assignment

I am trying to cast a object during an if - else statement as follows:

```
if(sourceSystem.equalsIgnoreCase("Src")) {
  MO object = (MO) transformer.create(message,sourceSystem,flowName);
} else {  
  UO object = (URO) transformer.create(message,sourceSystem,flowName);  
}
```

However it cannot be accessed outside of these?

```
validator.validate(object);
```

cannot be resolved to a variable. But surely the object is being created an assigned within the if-else statement. The object will always be created, therefore why is the compiler telling me it cannot be resolved to a variable. Yes I get local and global vairables however if I need to access a common method between UO and MO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't achieve what you want this way. Better try this:

```
Object object = transformer.create(message,sourceSystem,flowName);
if( object instanceof MO )
{
  //cast and use it as MO
}//if
else
{
  //cast and use it as UO
}//else
```

Inheritance could help you to group code of both blocks if UO and MO share the methods you use in each block.

Comment: How can I check that this is an instanceof MO? I am not aware how to do this in Java nor does the Object class contain the method for this.

Comment: ``instanceof`` is a java keyword and does exactly that. Just try it!

Answer (score 0):

You are actually declaring *two* variables named `object`. Each of them has a *very* limited scope, namely the block they are found in.

Assuming for a second that you *could* access the variables *after* the `if` statement completes: what would the type of `object` be in that case?

You need to declare a variable *before* the `if` and assign to that in both cases. You'll need to decide on a single type for this, however. In the worst case you need to use `Object`.

Answer (score 0):

Declare it outside the if blocks.

```
YourParentType object;
if(sourceSystem.equalsIgnoreCase("Src"))
    {
    object = (MO) transformer.create(message,sourceSystem,flowName);
    }
    else{
    object = (URO) transformer.create(message,sourceSystem,flowName);
    }
```

- MO and URO are related objects, you you may want to have a common parent for these. This class is what I mean by `YourParentType`
- What you are trying to do is similar to the [Factory Design Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern). You will find that this kind of `if`s repeat in may places in your code. You can move them to a "Factory" class. (Or use the `transformer` as a factory by moving the `if` into it, depending on what it does.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
MO MOObject = null;
UO UOObject = null;
if(sourceSystem.equalsIgnoreCase("Src"))
{
    MOObject = (MO) transformer.create(message,sourceSystem,flowName);
}
else
{
    UOObject = (URO) transformer.create(message,sourceSystem,flowName);
}
```

Then in follow-up code can be based on which one of these was not `null`.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `object` are only known within the blocks. If you want to use `object` in validator, then do it like this:

```
Object object = null;
if(sourceSystem.equalsIgnoreCase("Src")) {
  object = transformer.create(message,sourceSystem,flowName);
} else {  
  object = transformer.create(message,sourceSystem,flowName);  
}
validator.validate(object);
```

or even much shorter

```
validator.validate(transformer.create(message, sourceSystem, flowName));
```

Note that casting is not required (as long as `create` returns the type that is used by `validate`)

Answer (score 0):

The most elegant way of doing this would be to declare an interface, (say MessageInterface) and have both your MO and URO objects implement it.

Then you'll have to do something like this:

```
MessageInterface messageObject;
if(sourceSystem.equalsIgnoreCase("Src")) {
    messageObject = (MO) transformer.create(message,sourceSystem,flowName);
} else {
    messageObject = (URO) transformer.create(message,sourceSystem,flowName);
}
validator.validate(object);
```

If you don't have direct access to declaration of MO and URO you can still do this by creating a wrapper for them that implements the above interface.